# How can I generalize the code which count lists of elements?

Tags: jquery

I have a code which count lists of elements:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    var length = $('ul#list_1').children('li').length;
    $(".disp_1").html(length);

    var length = $('ul#list_2').children('li').length;
    $(".disp_2").html(length);
}

</script>

(number of elements: <span class="disp_1"></span>)
<ul id="list_1">
    <li>element
    <li>element
</ul>

(number of elements: <span class="disp_2"></span>)
<ul id="list_2">
    <li>element
    <li>element
    <li>element
</ul>
```

My question is how can I generalize the jQuery code for N-number lists?

Comment: With common classes and data attributes.  Other than that, if your code currently works, and you are asking how to improve it, this is fairly off topic for StackOverflow and would be more on topic for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal case for jQuery's [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
  $('div.count-this').each((i, div) => {
    var $div = $(div);
    var length = $div.find('li').length;
    $div.children('disp').html(length);
  });
}

</script>

<div class="count-this">
  (number of elements: <span class="disp"></span>)
  <ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
  </ul>
<div>

<div class="count-this">
  (number of elements: <span class="disp"></span>)
  <ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
  </ul>
<div>

...
```

Alternatively, you could use an anonymous function, an arguably more idiomatic syntax for jQuery:

```
  $('div.count=this').each(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    var length = $div.children('li').length;
    $div.children('disp').html(length);
  });
```

---

*Note:* the second parameter for the function your pass into `each` is a DOM element, not a JQuery object, so you need to wrap it back up in order to use jQuery methods.  Something like this will result in an error:

```
  $('div.count-this').each((i, div) => {
    var length = div.find('li').length;
    div.children('disp').html(length);
  });
```

because `div` is an [`Element`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element), not a [`JQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object.

Comment: I tried this code, but unfortunately doesn't working. First remark is the object $('div.count=this') why contains '=' sign? Maybe it will instead: $('div.count-this'), but it still does not work.

Comment: There was another typo--I needed to use `find` instead of `children`, as `li` is not a direct child of that div.